# pandas groupby function will not sum >8 columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe that contains 13 text columns and 16 numeric columns (29 columns in total, around 13k rows).  I would like to aggregate the data by the first 13 columns and return the sum of the results for the 16 numeric columns.  I have tried the following:

```
df.groupby(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)[14,15,26,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29].sum()
```

but this returns an error "groupby() takes from 1 to 8 positional arguments but 14 were given"

I am essentially trying to do the following as it would be in SQL syntax:

```
select 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,sum(14),sum(15),sum(16),sum(17),sum(18),sum(19),sum(20),sum(21),sum(22),sum(23),sum(24),sum(25),sum(26),sum(27),sum(28),sum(29)
from df group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
```

I'd also like the process done in place so I end up with a dataframe the same shape as the old one (with fewer rows, obviously!)

any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I was able to solve this by naming the columns specifically in the groupby: new_grouped_data = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4',...])['col14','col15','col16','col17',...].sum())

Comment: note that after doing this you can use df.reset_index(level=df.index.names, inplace=True) to turn the grouped columns back from an index to columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more general approach that uses `.select_dtypes`([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)) to isolate numeric columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

numerical_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.tolist()
other_columns = df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number]).columns.tolist()

df.groupby(other_columns)[numerical_columns].sum()
```

As for why your code is not working, it is because you need to pass a **list** of column names to groupby.

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: I tried this but it resulted in a "Grouper and axis must be same length" error.  I did manage to solve the problem - see my comment to the original question

Comment: I have edited the answer explicitly converting columns from index to list.
This should fix the error

Comment: after doing this you can use df.reset_index(level=df.index.names, inplace=True) to turn the grouped columns back from an index to columns